# Log file of all transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I use `SP` and `linq`  and `Function` for work to SQL Server 2005

I want to any connection to DB.

The DB added that the information be deleted or edited or added(to DB) in a text file(log) or do anything to follow events held in the DB.

how can this work by SQL or asp.net

I like in any connection to DB save input/output connection

input:arguman that send to DB

output:DB Return or edit or delete recorded in DB

Comment: Aummmmmmmmmmm.. what do are you saying ??? Please take some time to improve your question and your name ;)

Comment: Which "LINQ"? LINQ-to-SQL? EF? what?

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little hard to follow, but if you simply want to log all LINQ access to the DB, then with something like LINQ-to-SQL you could use `DataContext.Log` and specify a writer (be careful though - don't give it the file *directly*, as you'll block parallel activity).

I personally think this is a bad idea though - data volume is usually prohibitive for this. Databases get very busy.

If that isn't sufficient, and you have other operations to log - you could try an intercepting DbConnection, a bit like the profiled connection in [mvc-mini-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/). This works well with LINQ-to-SQL (EF... harder). But again - data volume is a big issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own small API like OpenDBConnection(); CloseDBConnection(); and use it all arround the code inyour C# program . Add log functionality to that methods and you basically done.

As @Marc says the amount of the data is one of the problems here not actually an implementation, but it depends on current and future scale of your project that only you may know.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: this work has very very cost for DB if i have 10000 connection

Comment: It will cost by the way. It depends, I repeat, on scale you have and if you really want to log everything.